# How to change line spacing in a item(not between items) of enumerate environment?

Tags: enumerate

I didn't find a good answer, so I use this code:

```
\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=4em,topsep=10pt,itemsep=0pt \baselineskip=12pt}
```

But that doesn't work properly.

```
sadkhflkashdfklhkahfksdlfhlkahfk

\begin{enumerate}
\item sdkjfhalskdfhjklashjfkdhsflahsdfhkalsdfhla sadkjfkasdhf  ksdahf aklfh asjkfhdska asfkl asdfhlk alkhsf
\item sdkahfaklsd sdfjklh aklsf hdkls hfklsd fhdkla dkl sdjkl la sdkl
\end{enumerate}

sdklfhajklhfjkasdhfasdkljfhaskldfhklasdfh
```

You can see this code will generate a unwanted spacing in the last line.Obviously, the spacing between last two lines is more than the first two lines.

My \baselineskip is set to 20pt in document environment.

[image]

Comment: Of course, I can set \baselineskip to 12pt before the last line, and reset it to 20pt after the last line, but I don't like this.

Comment: Make a complete example that can be used for tests.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `\end{enumerate}` places the last baseline to try to get a gap equal to `\topsep`, assuming `\baselineskip=12pt`.  You can fix it by redefining enumerate to remove the extra 8pt.

Note, using this approach sort of makes enumitem pointless.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{leftmargin=4em,itemsep=0pt,topsep=10pt}

\let\oldenumerate=\enumerate
\let\oldendenumerate=\endenumerate
\def\enumerate{\bgroup\baselineskip=12pt\oldenumerate}
\def\endenumerate{\oldendenumerate\egroup\vskip-8pt}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{20pt}
sadkhflkashdfklhkahfksdlfhlkahfk

\begin{enumerate}
\item sdkjfhalskdfhjklashjfkdhsflahsdfhkalsdfhla sadkjfkasdhf  ksdahf aklfh asjkfhdska asfkl asdfhlk alkhsf
\item sdkahfaklsd sdfjklh aklsf hdkls hfklsd fhdkla dkl sdjkl la sdkl
\end{enumerate}

sdklfhajklhfjkasdhfasdkljfhaskldfhklasdfh
\end{document}
```

Comment: pointless? What's the meaning of it?

Comment: @feikong - Everything enumitem does can be done by modifying the enumerate environment directly.  In particular, one could set \leftmargin, \itemsep and \topsep along with \baselineskip.